# After deleting row from SQLite DB in C# the Reader throws "Object reference not set .."

Tags: c#, database, forms, sqlite

Functionality is basic at the moment. I can add rows fairly simply, and when I do so I update a listBox, however if I delete a row, or start the program without the initial row (from Insert Query) the SQLiteDataReader throws this exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Its very peculiar, and that is the error that is thrown if I start the program without the initial row (which is added on DB creation). It also occurs everytime I start the program and the DB isn't freshly created. If I create the DB, close the program, reopen the program and connect to the DB, the reader gives that error.

Here is some code.

```
    SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=test.sqlite;Version=3;");
    SQLiteCommand cmd;
    query = "SELECT * FROM Table";
    db.Open();

    SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //This is the line that throws
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       //read and do work. (This section has been tested and works 
    }
    reader.Close()
    db.Close();
```

Might be worth noting, that the queries work fine if the table has just been made. Its only once a row has been deleted, or the program restarted without a fresh DB creation that this error pops up. Can't seem to see why it's doing it. Doesn't seem very logical, but I imagine it's a stupid bug.

All help appreciated.

*Reference: Using the System.Data.SQLite.dll*

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize cmd. It's null.

Try

```
query = "SELECT * FROM Table";
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, db);
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not instantiate `cmd`.

```
SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=test.sqlite;Version=3;");
    SQLiteCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    query = "SELECT * FROM Table";
    command.CommandText = query;
    db.Open();

    SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //This is the line that throws
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       //read and do work. (This section has been tested and works 
    }
    reader.Close()
    db.Close();
```

Comment: God damnit. Can't believe I missed that. Forgot to write that in when copying code from anther class. Thanks!